# Having issues when starting Lnd. Lncli create command provides no output

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

I have lnd running on MacOs (m2 machine) with Bitcoind as a back end. Bitcoin is in my external SSD drive.

When I start Lnd, I am able to get to the lncli create option, but the lmcli create command will not provide any response. It gets stuck.

I have to close Lnd due to this and it seems this is the issue I get.

```
^C2023-12-06 09:54:13.546 [INF] LTND: Received interrupt
2023-12-06 09:54:13.546 [INF] LTND: Shutting down...
2023-12-06 09:54:13.546 [INF] LTND: Gracefully shutting down.
2023-12-06 09:54:13.546 [ERR] LTND: unable to set up wallet password listeners: shutting down
2023-12-06 09:54:13.546 [ERR] LTND: Shutting down because error in main method: error creating wallet config: unable to set up wallet password listeners: shutting down
2023-12-06 09:54:13.547 [INF] LTND: Shutdown complete

error creating wallet config: unable to set up wallet password listeners: shutting down
logout
```

My lnd.conf looks like this

```
bitcoin.active=1
bitcoin.mainnet=true
bitcoin.node=bitcoind 
listen=0.0.0.0:9734
rpclisten=localhost:11009
restlisten=0.0.0.0:8180

bitcoind.rpchost=localhost:8332
bitcoind.rpcuser=...
bitcoind.rpcpass=...
bitcoind.zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
bitcoind.zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333
bitcoin.chaindir=/Volumes/BitcoinSSD/BitcoinCore
```

My bitcoin.conf looks like this

```
rpcuser=...
rpcpassword=...
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcport=8332
datadir=/Volumes/BitcoinSSD/BitcoinCore
server=1
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333
```

Any idea what this could be due to?
I've tried restarting both, restarting my computer, reinstalling lnd from source and binaries download.
Your help would be much appreciated.